# How to build a network-coding based Converge-Cast wireless sensor network in Omnet with INET

Tags: c++, networking, omnet++, inet

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSuKN.png)

I want to build a basic converge-cast wireless network to test the network-coding in Omnet with INET. The basic structure of this network is shown in the Figure 1. There are two sources S1 and S1, two relay nodes C1 and C2, and one destination D. in this topology S1, C1 and C2 are within each other’s broadcast range, and S2, C1 and C2 are within each other’s broadcast range. In a certain time period, two groups of packets X = {x1, x2, …, X|x|} from S1 to D and Y = {y1, y2, …, Y|y|} from S2 to D are received by C1 and C2. So C1, C2 can encode X and Y together before forwarding them.

(1) *Overhearing*: Every node should work in a promiscuous mode. So the relay C2 and C1 can overhear packets transmitted from S1 and S2 to D respectively.

(2) *Encoding*: When relay C1 receives the native packets X and Y, it encodes these packets together and broadcasts the coded packet to receivers D. The same procedure will be done in C2. The encode operation is merely a simple random linear combination of native packets as Z1=ga1*X1+gb1*Y1, where the ga1 and gb1 are the coefficients randomly selected from a q-order Galois field GF(q). And Z1 is the coded packet. The coefficients will be included in the header of the coded packets.

(3) *Decoding:* D will decode all packets in X and Y using the received coded packets Z1 from C1 and C2 together.

(4) *Benefit*: For example, The packets x1 and x2 are to be joined up with each
other in D. However, the link from S2 to C2 (LS2→C2 ) fails. Evidently, in case of non-network-coding schemes, at least one retransmission is required to ensure the success of packet delivery. But it is different if the idea of network coding is employed. Since C1 can overhear x2, it would combine x1 and x2 by means of XOR or linear network coding [2] (in fact, XOR is a special kind of linear network coding scheme with GF(2)). Assume the coded packet is (x1 ⊕ x2). And likewise, C2 can overhear x1 and just only forward it to D for it only get one packet. Finally, D is able to recover x2 by reXOR the coded packet with x1, as shown in Fig.1(b). Hence, network coding in converge-cast is able to reduce the probability of retransmission.

1. I would like to use ieee802.11 standard of radio transmission which is usually used in wireless network. I hope this standard can control the link reliability or packet deliver ratio.
2. For simple, let S1 and S2 are synchronized. I'm not quite sure how long it should wait for packet from S2, can you give me an advice ?
3. Yes, I want to multiply each 8 bits with ga1. How about mod the overflow    numbers.
4. I want to add the values. If the multiply and add operation is hard to achieve. We can simply the recover operation. For instance, as C1 and C2 will receive both x1 and x2 and they will choose coefficient to multiply them. When the sink node D receive the coded packet, We can put these four coefficients in a 2x2 matrix like [C11, C12; C21, C22] to check weather they are independent, if they are independent, we can assume that the packet x1 and x2 can be successfully decoded.

Comment: There are some issues. **1.** In IEEE802.11 there is no explicit range concept. During reception a SNR and an interference level are calculated and they decide whether a frame will be correctly received or not. So the only way to control a range is manipulation of threshold values of SNR. **2.** The synchronization of sending frames by S1 and S2 is a strong and hard assumption and it hard to achieve in real network (of course in simulation it's easy to model). I advice you to introduce some timeout, C1 after receiving a frame from S1 will wait some time for a frame from S2.

Comment: **3.** A frame may contain **any** numbers you want to send. You may use integer or float or double or any other formats of numbers. You should only show the structure of this packet i.e. show the fields that the packet contains. For example this way: Packet XPAK contains: 1) filed srcAddr, integer, 8 bits 2) field dstAddr, integer, 8 bits 3) code, double, 64 bits. And try to avoid to write about multiplying a packet by ga1, instead write "multiply code filed value by ga1. The same with adding.

Comment: Sorry, I should make more specific. 1. Is there any other radio transmission standards can control the range. If no, I think IEEE802.11 is fine, as it can manipulate the threshold values of SNR to control the link reliability. And SNR is also can be measured easier than link reliability in the real network. 2. How about 10ms ? C1 will wait 10ms for a frame from S2 after it receives a frame from S1. 3. I will find the basic structure of packet in my notes later and let you know.

Comment: 3. Packet contains: 1). Source address, integer,8 bits  2). Destination address, integer,8bits 3). data block's number,integer, 8bits 4). block's length, integer, 8 bits 5). coding coefficient, double, 8 bits  6)encoded datadouble, 64 bits.  There is a mistake Itold before, the multiply and adding is different in Galois field, it is a little complicate and I will check it  and tell you later.

Comment: Hi Jerzy, I need to make clear a few steps in multiplication in GF which will simplify the calculation. So I need another one or two day.

Comment: Hi Jerzy,  I put the calculation in the question called the calculation in the Galois field. Could you give me an example code like this structure ?